# Should .rvm and all its subdirectories be owned by user instead of root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, root

I have a ~/.rvm file that has some subdirectories owned by user (anthony) and some owned by root. This is causing issues when I am trying to `gem install`.

I am tempted to run `sudo chown -R anthony:staff ~/.rvm` so I have full user control over the entire .rvm folder.

Is this ok/desired?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all files / directores should be owned by user, to fix it run:

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

to avoid this problem in future just try to avoid using `sudo` or `rvmsudo` it should be never required *(rvm uses `sudo` internally when it is required)*.